# Cloud SQL high latency

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-sql

I just deployed a small (1cpu, 600mb ram) db instance for Postgres.
With barely any load, db is very slow, average latency is 1,5s.
Ping for the DB IP is 190ms avg. I know it is high, but still it is a small amount of the total latency.

```
pgbench "sslmode=verify-ca sslrootcert=server-ca.pem sslcert=client-cert.pem sslkey=client-key.pem hostaddr={{IP}} port=5432 user={{user}} dbname=my-database"

Password:
starting vacuum...end.
transaction type: <builtin: TPC-B (sort of)>
scaling factor: 1
query mode: simple
number of clients: 1
number of threads: 1
number of transactions per client: 10
number of transactions actually processed: 10/10
latency average = 1576.916 ms
tps = 0.634149 (including connections establishing)
tps = 0.697559 (excluding connections establishing)
```

Is that latency normal? CPU and memory utilization is below 10%. Can you  help me finding the remaining 1400ms ?

I tested the db with pgbench. I want to minimize  the latency average.
I am developing django app, and latencies are noticable by the user.

Comment: Ping is a small data packet so it does not really apply to a database load. This question needs more information. **Add as text update to question text**: 1) Postgres version. 2) Network distance between client and server.  3) The size of the data load? 4) Number of connections and are you using pooling? 5) Also when using `pgbench` there is a lot more going on then just making connections. See [pgbench](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgbench.html), the information under *-I init_steps*.

Comment: The database isn't that slow, it's your network that's causing delays: The database is busy waiting for the next query.

Comment: Ping uses ICMP which does not account for TCP connection setup, certificate exchange, certificate verification, negotiation, key exchange, etc. However, your problem is caused by network latency between the client and the database. Not with the database itself.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. I had no idea that remote location can cause lag that huge. I will move the DB closer to me, and it should help a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default pgbench transaction include 7 sequential round-trips to the database.  So the ping explains pretty much all of the observed latency. There are a variety of things you can do to reduce this, but unless you can do those same things to Django, it seems rather pointless to explore them.

Comment: thanks for the help. I will move the DB closer to me, and check the latency.

Answer (score 0):

After changing DB location, and reducing the ping from 200 to 20ms, overall latency decreased from 1600 to 200ms. I had no idea, it can cause lag that huge.

Comment: Add details such as where the client is located and the database (old and new locations). Details make a difference.

Comment: I moved the DB from us-central-1 (ping 200ms, latency 1600ms) to europe-central2-a (ping 20ms, latency 200ms)